# bootstrap well goes on multiple lines on small screen

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

In my development environment I upgraded to rails 4.1.0 and removed some old bootstrap pieces. Now, the bootstrap Wells on my homepage are no longer working on mobile width screens.

Here is my last commit that is currently not applied to production yet. https://github.com/kacole2/JumpSquares/commit/afbcfbecdb3dc785dc6cb8469fadd2452464cef1

If you go to the production site at http://www.jumpsquares.net and shrink the width, it works as it should. However, when I'm running in development it looks messed up as seen here:

[image: Imgur]

the only code that was changes in the github link was removing some leftover bootstrap stuff and changing the home screen banner.

Here is the code that should be applied

```html
<div class="page-header">   
   <div class="row">    
     <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 well well-sm">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">     
            <%=link_to image_tag("twitter-avatars/johnnie1.png"), "https://twitter.com/JohnnieITatDell"  %>  
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/JohnnieITatDell">@JohnnieITatDell</a>: "JumpSquares is freakishly brilliant."
          </div>
     </div>

     <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 well well-sm col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">     
            <%=link_to image_tag("twitter-avatars/herseyc.png"), "https://twitter.com/herseyc"  %>   
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/herseyc">@herseyc</a>: "Fantastic home lab bookmark tool" (<a href="http://www.vhersey.com/2014/03/jumpsquares-fantastic-home-lab-bookmark-tool/"><font color="#18bc9c">blog post</font></a>)
          </div>
     </div>

     <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 well well-sm col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">     
            <%=link_to image_tag("twitter-avatars/vnelson.png"), "https://twitter.com/vNelsonTX"  %>     
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/vNelsonTX">@vNelsonTX</a>: "Really digging JumpSquares, great job!"
          </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 well well-sm col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">     
            <%=link_to image_tag("twitter-avatars/h0bbel.png"), "https://twitter.com/h0bbel"  %>     
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/h0bbel">@h0bbel</a>: "We discussed JumpSquares on <a href="http://vsoup.net/2014/01/vsoup-general-purple-is-better-than-agent-purple-any-day-40/#podPressPlayerSpace_1"><font color="#18bc9c">vSoup</font></a> today. I think you should listen to it" (31:30)
          </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 well well-sm col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">     
            <%=link_to image_tag("twitter-avatars/mdent.png"), "https://twitter.com/mikedent13"  %>  
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/mikedent13">@mikedent13</a>: "You’ve changed the way I manage my bookmarks with JumpSquares. Just flat out awesome!"
          </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adding an additional row to each of the wells

```
<div class="page-header">   
   <div class="row">    
     <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 well well-sm">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">     
            <%=link_to image_tag("twitter-avatars/johnnie1.png"), "https://twitter.com/JohnnieITatDell"  %>  
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/JohnnieITatDell">@JohnnieITatDell</a>: "JumpSquares is freakishly brilliant."
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 well well-sm col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">     
            <%=link_to image_tag("twitter-avatars/herseyc.png"), "https://twitter.com/herseyc"  %>   
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/herseyc">@herseyc</a>: "Fantastic home lab bookmark tool" (<a href="http://www.vhersey.com/2014/03/jumpsquares-fantastic-home-lab-bookmark-tool/"><font color="#18bc9c">blog post</font></a>)
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 well well-sm col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">     
            <%=link_to image_tag("twitter-avatars/vnelson.png"), "https://twitter.com/vNelsonTX"  %>     
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/vNelsonTX">@vNelsonTX</a>: "Really digging JumpSquares, great job!"
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 well well-sm col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">     
            <%=link_to image_tag("twitter-avatars/h0bbel.png"), "https://twitter.com/h0bbel"  %>     
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/h0bbel">@h0bbel</a>: "We discussed JumpSquares on <a href="http://vsoup.net/2014/01/vsoup-general-purple-is-better-than-agent-purple-any-day-40/#podPressPlayerSpace_1"><font color="#18bc9c">vSoup</font></a> today. I think you should listen to it" (31:30)
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 well well-sm col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">     
            <%=link_to image_tag("twitter-avatars/mdent.png"), "https://twitter.com/mikedent13"  %>  
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/mikedent13">@mikedent13</a>: "You’ve changed the way I manage my bookmarks with JumpSquares. Just flat out awesome!"
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```